# Referring to well-known "Titles" in US Law without the Act/Amendment they come from

Tags: words, proper-nouns

The current assignment in my Japanese course is to write an essay that in some way discusses gender (in)equality. In the US, in the context of education, if one says "Title IX", most people will understand it as the Title IX *specifically* from the Education Amendments of 1972. (*Even* if they do not know of the wider set of amendments: "Title IX" is effectively its own well-known entity.)

In my essay I first write

> この法律は1964年にケネディ大統領の後継者によって可決され、第7タイトルは就職において民族、性別、出身によっての差別を禁止した。

And later

> 第7タイトルは教育機関で男女平等を保障しなかった。1972年、「第9タイトル」と呼ばれる法律が可決され、…

However, today my professor approached me and asked me about "article" vs "title" in English / about whether or not 「第9条」 would be a better fit; I tried to Google about the usage of both words in US law and wasn't able to find anything concrete. We decided I may get more help asking the internet.

My worry is that, while 「第7条」 makes sense for the former case (I am introducing it as the 7th section of the passed law), for the latter case "Title IX" is really more of a proper noun, and the meaning of 「第9条」 being its own separate thing (coming from a distinct place compared to Title VII of the Civil Rights Act of 1964) will be lost.

1. Is 「第9タイトル」 meaningful when translating with a native-Japanese-speaking target audience?
2. Are my worries about 「第9条」unfounded, and it'll be fine to replace all of my usages of タイトル with 条?

Comment: 編 seems to be used for "title" here: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/合衆国法典

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a technical term. You just need to find the accepted translation. As aguijonazo noted, it seems to be 編:

> [タイトルナイン](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%83%8A%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3-2119430)
>
> アメリカ合衆国の公的高等教育機関における男女の機会均等を定めた連邦法の修正法。教育改正法第9**編**とも訳される。

---

The Chinese translation seems to use 条: [教育法修正案第九条](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%95%99%E8%82%B2%E6%B3%95%E4%BF%AE%E6%AD%A3%E6%A1%88%E7%AC%AC%E4%B9%9D%E6%9D%A1)